# How to get an OUTPUT parameter from a stored procedured in an Airflow DAG?

Tags: sql-server, airflow

I have to execute a stored procedure in SQL Server with an Airflow DAG:

```py
) as dag:

    SP_P1 = JdbcOperator(
            task_id='Exec_SP_SQLServer',
            sql='declare @Errcod int; exec ARG.dbo.ABL_SP_DELIVERY_REQUEST_CFW_CONTAINER @Errcod output;',
            jdbc_conn_id='jdbc_sql_arg',
            autocommit=True,
            dag=dag,
            )
```

After the execution of the SP, I need to get the value of the `@Errcod` output parameter to ask for it in the Airflow DAG. Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Well, we don't know what's going on in your `Exec_SP_SQLServer` task, but have you tried to select it? i.e.: `... SELECT @Errcod AS [ErrorCodeOrSomething];`